# Make Div Clickable without Javascript or <a> or href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a small issue with a div .

I have a font awesome icon in my div that i want to be clickable without using the a or href tag .

Javascript - i would prefer not unless its the only option

```
<h3 class="panel-title">

<div class="panel-x" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUser">

Title

</div> 

</h3>
```

I want to make the div class : panel-x clickable .

Now , when i hover on it , the cursor just changes to the I symbol instead of the hand .

The icon for the div is generated in css.

```
.panel-x:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f057";
}
```

Comment: have a look at this [link](http://ctrlq.org/code/19639-turn-div-clickable-link)

Comment: if you want to register functionality with the onclick event on the div then you have to use some js.

Comment: try cursor : hand in css and for click functionality bind an event to the div

Comment: What do you want to do when user clicks on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `cursor: pointer`:

```css
.panel-x {
  cursor: pointer; /* hand cursor */
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background: ghostwhite;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 11px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
}
.panel-x:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px;
}
.panel-x:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-x" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUser">Title</div>

<div class="panel-x" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUser">There goes a long text</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `cursor: pointer`?

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery you can do like this

```
$(".panel-x").on('click',function(e){
  // code logic here
  e.preventDefault();    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this
    .panel-x{
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        content: "\f057";
        cursor: pointer;
    }

Answer (score 1):

try this one

CSS :

```
.panel-x:after {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content: "\f057";
}


div.panel-x { cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; }
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.panel-x").on('click',function(){

        console.log("clicked");
    })
})
```